# What is the iOS alternative to a radio button?

Tags: gui-design, ios, interface, apple

There is a radio button in android and WEB but what is the best alternative in iOS? And please don't say segmented control becuase it's not working in my case.

The case is a list of items 3-6 which have 1-3 words of text each and it is required to pick 1.

[image: Screenshot of web radio buttons that i need to adapt for ios]

Comment: This does not seem [related to Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Choosing what inreface elements to use IS part of graphic design. Important one.

Comment: Why does the segmented control not working in your case?

Comment: This is indeed a question more suited to SE.UX or a question for SE.StackOverflow...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a UX question, not a graphic design question.

Comment: Use a radio button.

Comment: @plainclothes - Even though Apple (almost -> Xerox) invented the radio button, unfortunately, it is not provided in the native iOS UI API any longer...  One is guided to use the god awful "picker" control instead :-(

Comment: @Greenonline The user punishing picker is the very reason you roll your own radio button. I'm afraid Apple is going to fall fast under the influence of Mr Ive.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Usually this is done using a table view, which is basically a list of items as well, only with a checkmark instead of a radio button. Sometimes such lists are on a new 'page' in the navigation structure. How this fits in your navigational structure depends on the context.

[image: List of items]

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a [highly customizable radio button control](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton) for iOS. It supports both `obj-c` and `swift`. Hope it helps!

[image]

Comment: you did a nice work on this. But setting the `otherButtons` is a little bit confusing for new developers. Please create a blog or video tutorial on this. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @abhi1992 thx, I'll add something in the README.

Comment: Example for how to connect `otherButtons`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729079/implementation-of-dlradiobutton-ios-objective-c

Answer (score 4):

#### UIPickerView

You may want to use a `UIPickerView` for something like that.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html

[image]

---

#### UITableView

There’s plenty of other alternatives that could be good, it really depends on the app’s structure. You’ll notice that lots of the options in `Settings` use a master/detail pattern for things that are effectively radio buttons. It’s a good way to go, especially with limited screen space.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing an iOS app, you should probably use the Picker control.

As detailed in Apple's [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Controls.html): "A *picker* displays a set of values from which a user picks one."

Comment: Pickers don't feel intuitive, yet this is the only native "alternative" that acts as RadioButtons.

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't have a default radio button. You can either use a third-party plugin to create a custom radio button like [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/radiobutton) or you can use iOS other default elements:

- a picker

[image]

- a switch

[image]

Comment: I don't believe a switch is a good fit for this problem; it's not at all conventional for an iOS switch to affect other switches.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. It would work only if it was a multiple choice question.

Comment: A switch implies that you can flip various options at will, without effect to the others, and without limitation. Radio buttons (and the miserable iOS picker) enforces a single selection.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this easy seven step tutorial - [iPhone UIButton tutorial: Radio Buttons](http://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/blog/iphone/iphone-uibutton-tutorial-radio-buttons/) by Mobisoft. It is what I have used for the past couple of years. There is too much code to replicate here, so beware of link death in the future. The steps are below:

1. Create a window based application in Xcode and name it “MIRadioButtonGroup”.
2. Create new “MIRadioButtonGroup.h” and “MIRadioButtonGroup.m” files
   which extend from UIView. (Classes >> Add >> New File >> Objective C
   Class. Select UIView in the “subclass of” list.)
3. Create a new group in the Classes folder and name it
   “MIRadioButtonGroup”. Drag the “MIRadioButtonGroup .h” and
   “MIRadioButtonGroup .m” files into the group.Now, add the images
   “radio-on.png” and “radio-off.png” to the group.
4. Open the “MIRadioButtonGroup.h” file and make the changes in it, as suggested on the site.
5. Open the “MIRadioButtonGroup.m” file and put the respective code in it.
6. Now that we have created the “MIRadioButtonGroup” files, put the following code in the “MIRadioButtonGroupAppDelegate.m” file so that we can test them.
7. Save, build and run the project. The output will be Output1. Now uncomment the commented lines one by one and observe the output. It will be Output 2, Output 3 and Output 1 respectively.

[image: iOS Radio Buttons]

You can download the source code [here](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/MIRadioButtonGroup.zip).

Comment: Stumbled upon this: https://github.com/onegray/RadioButton-ios