# What is the best native iOS solution for a Radio Button with just two options?

Tags: ios, selection, radio-buttons, cards, native-app

The challenge I'm faced with is that I have a horizontally scrolling series of cards that have two common questions for each item, say, `Did you perform activity x?` and `Did you perform activity y?`, and the answer is to be filled in objectively with a `YES` or a `NO`.

Of course, radio buttons are the go to solution to look up to, but unfortunately, iOS doesn't seem to natively include a good solution for Radio Buttons (Please enlighten me if I'm wrong).

If my layout were tabular, I would have used the native iOS table-based radio options, as illustrated in [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/78872/what-is-the-ios-alternative-to-a-radio-button). But since I have to incorporate the solution within a card, I'd prefer to limit the size of the card as well.

Switches are not a solution either as they are not suited for Q&A-like copy, but instead are rather suited for action-oriented features (say turn on Flight Mode, or Activate `this` plan etc.).

I am currently working on the UX of an SDK and would prefer to use native components as much as possible.

Please note that I have already checked the previously existing question regarding [the iOS alternative to a radio button](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/78872/what-is-the-ios-alternative-to-a-radio-button) and that isn't the solution I'm looking for as my layout is not tabular, but card-based instead.

Comment: Please be kind enough to at least leave a comment on why you're downvoting this question.

Comment: Why none of the answers for the linked question wouldn't be fitting in the context of the cards?

Comment: @locationunknown Because I'm looking for a native solution. iOS doesn't natively support radio buttons. Pickers would take multiple clicks instead of just one when compared to radio buttons. And Radio Groups, that are supported by iOS are a solution aimed at a tabular layout which won't fit in well within a card-based layout. That why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how Apple do yes/no answers in their ResearchKit application - http://researchkit.org/docs/docs/Survey/CreatingSurveys.html

[image: ResearchKit - yes/no answer 1]
[image: ResearchKit - yes/no answer 2]

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for these screens. I don't know how, but I completely missed out on these screens from ResearchKit. But yeah, this absolutely serves my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the question cards Google Maps uses to get information from users about locations. I occasionally get alerts on my phone that pop up cards with questions about places I've been. It usually asks for yes/no responses or star-ratings. Usually there are many questions related to each place.

**They use buttons for the yes/no responses.**  The advantage of buttons over toggles or radio buttons or such is it takes a single click to respond with a button vs two clicks for toggles and similar options.  The clicks add up to a substantial number when there are many questions to answer.

If you are concerned about mistakes, log the Q&A somewhere that the user can review and correct them.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]